# Find BIOS update for HP Pavilion xt966

Tags: bios, bsd, freenas

I installed FreeNAS on a HP Pavilion xt966. Every three seconds or so I message comes up on the console.

```
acpi_tz0: _TMP value is absurd, ignored (-270.2C)
```

From what I have been able to find this is because of a bug in the BIOS... but I have yet to find an update for it.

HP's site only shows drivers.

Anyone know where to find a BIOS update for this unit?

INFO:
[FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/)

Version     0.7.1 Shere (revision 5024)

Built on    Tue Jan 26 00:11:57 UTC 2010

OS Version  FreeBSD 7.2-RELEASE-p6 (revision 199506)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the xt966 runs an Intel 850 chipset on a motherboard from ASUS. Going from ASUS's website it looks like there are only 4-5 motherboards they sold at that time. (The P4T and it's children) Check on the motherboard physically if it has a model number or some other information. ASUS will probably have the latest BIOS on their website.

Comment: Where did you find out who made the motherboard?

Comment: i found a specifications page on hp's site 

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=46171&prodTypeId=12454&prodSeriesId=46171&objectID=bph06626#A4

Comment: D'oh. Nice one!

Comment: Did you end up finding it?

Comment: Life got busy... I downloaded all the manuals and non of them look like this one.

Comment: So I decided to just see what happens and downloaded the update for just the P4t. But now I need a boot disk... I don't think I even own floppy. And the boot cd hasn't been working out. It sure would be nice to read the CPU temp.